Are there Askey Scheme hypergeometrics greater than 4F3(4)?
Wilson and Racah polynomials (4F3(4)) are the highest-order hypergeometrics on the Wikipedia page. I am asking if there are higher-order hypergeometrics than that (5F4(5) for example) and if there is a resource on that.

Share more information about a problem

@Guruprasad   I'm asking if Hypergeometric functions of a higher order than what is listed here exists: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Askey_scheme                                      For instance, does 5F4(5) exist?
